# How to know which Kernel is better?

Tags: classification, svm, kernel-trick

I am working on an Image recognition software -

My first question is since I already explicitly turm my training images to features vector (and also my test images) what is the point of using Kernels to begin with? since, from what i understand, they are supposed to "save me the trouble" of explicitly computing the feature map for every point in the trainint set.

Second question: Given a specific feature map (for instance in image recognition: size, color, texture, brightness etc) How can I know if I should use a Linear Kernel, Polynomal Kernel, RBF or maybe some custome kernel? and if custome is the answer how to design it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernels don't save you the trouble of vectorizing images. In fact, no learning method does. Of course, you can write a wrapper to do this once and be done with it. Kernels *do* often save you the trouble of identifying a suitable feature space, through the use of the kernel trick.

You can find out which kernel function is best in two ways: (i) try different kernels and see what works and (ii) read about what comparable applications have used. The former is most reliable by far, and [can be automated using hyperparameter optimization libraries like Optunity](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notebooks/notebooks/sklearn-svc.html#tune-svc-without-deciding-the-kernel-in-advance).

If you want to obtain good representations and learn distinctive features automatically you should have a look at [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning).

Comment: Thank you so much for you response, it was very helpfull!